# handling null model attributes in a backbone / underscore template

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, backbone-model, underscore.js-templating

I have a model whose data is displayed in a backbone view/underscore template.

I setup the template in my view like this:

```
return Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'officeAlerts',
        template: _.template(OfficeAlertsTmpl, null, { variable: 'm' }),
```

And in my template, I have lines like this to display the model data:

```
<span class="textForEmployer">{%- m.officeName %} has no alerts.</span>
```

When all the data is there, everything works fine.  The problem I have is with nulls.  If a model attribute happens to be null, the whole page doesn't load and I get a null reference error in the browser console.

Is there a way to check/catch nulls so that it doesn't stop the whole page from loading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a condition like this:

```
<span class ="textForEmployer"> <%=  m ? m.officeName: "" %> has no alerts.</span>
```